# Creating dynamic links between features

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, polyline-creation, catchment-area

I currently want to create links between 2 features. Ie., I have 2 basins that flow out and I want to use a line/polyline to have a link out of them and both point to a common 3rd feature, indicating that both basins have flows to the 3rd feature (area).

Is there a way  I can do that or do I have to create a polyline feature class myself with the two endpoints being the location of the basin and the outflow area? If I do it this way, when I move my basin around, the polyline won't follow.  Is there a way I can make a LINK between the two?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

To make it where you can move a basin and have the polyline follow, you can set up a [topology](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000000sp000000.htm) between the point and line layer.  The rule most relevant to you is the Endpoint Must Be Covered By rule.  This rule enforces that the endpoint of a line must be covered by a point feature in another feature class.

Comment: Thanks for the info, is there a way where i can enforce "Endpoint must be covered by" rule to be inside a polygon instead of a point, since I want the user to be able to create lines that links the subcatchment, if I use that rule, do i have to link the line to the edge vertices of the polygon?

Comment: Also, I followed this link http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=159&f=1710&t=249834 but its still pretty vague, do you have any resource that I can follow with to get a more clear head start on creating links? Thanks